# Are there any disadvantages running Visual Studio as Administrator

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Usually I programm WinForms and never run into any "You have to run VS as Admin" problems but since I stated work into MVC this is giving a headache. E.g. [using IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440242/creating-virtual-directory-for-asp-net-web-project). There are [lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261724/why-run-visual-studio-as-run-as-administrator) for what you need the Administrator Mode in VS but my question is, when I start developing my projects in Administrator Mode are there any disadvantages or problems I will run into compared with User Mode?
According to what I have read yet it looks like standard to develop via admin mode. Is that impression correct?

Answer (score 1):

Not any more it isn't. It used to be, but then developers found out that when users run their programs not in Admin mode they sometimes stop working, so people don't use their programs.

The only time you might need Admin mode is when you have to debug a program running as another user - either because it's a service running under LOCAL SYSTEM, or it's a web sire running under IIS using the default IIS identity.

If you're developing a Web Site, VS should be using the development web server included in VS which runs as the developer and doesn't require Admin.